# Intellisense in VS Code - current advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense, visual-studio-code

What is the up-to-the-minute advice on getting javascript / jQuery Intellisense in VS Code (1.4.0)? Most answers I have found use TSD, which I understand is (albeit very recently) deprecated.

I have a jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I (in this project) have a folder structure open that contains many "websites". I have tried putting the file both at the very root level of the folder structure and at the root level of what I am currently using (i.e. that which i'll run http-server from to fire up the site). No joy.

I have had Intellisense sort of working in other projects, i.e. I can "Go to Definition", and get a method parameters popup, but I have never successfully got the "type . and see the method list" thing which is what I would dearly love!!

After a search for answers yesterday, I tried `npm install typings --global`, but still nothing at all.

(I am also running eslint - in the unlikely event that that makes any odds (interference?) )

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3):

Typings for many popular libraries are available [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), including jQuery.

VS Code can use these with both JavaScript and TypeScript.

As for your JS code, the editor cannot infer all type information due to the nature of JS, so intellisense is limited. If type safety and intellisense support is important for your project, you may consider using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

More details on [JavaScript support in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript).

Comment: I guess that will have to be the answer - but it will have to wait until I have time to research it. God, I miss Winforms development with the later versions of Visual Studio SO MUCH... WYSIWIG design surface, so, no spending forever getting things to align or scale, full intellisense ... *shrug* what can you do? Times are hard...